# How can I match number but not string using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have 2 strings :

```
Http://localhost:8080/myhost/abc/getResource 
Http://localhost:8080/myhost/abc/getResource/123
```

How do I make the rule for the second if I use the regex for the 1st using `.*getResource*`.

Comment: Is the question about grep or java? What have you tried?

Comment: Well, `.*getResource.*`?

Comment: Sorry.. yes I tried .*getResource*. But that seems to match the second url as well.. Thank you.

Comment: Use `.*getResource$`

Comment: The regex to much only number  ^\\d+$

Comment: I'd think `/getResource/[0-9]+$`. This `.*getResource*` is allowing for multiple `e`s. (Also I don't JAVA so perhaps something is wrong with this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *don't* want to "match the second url as well", you may want to check if there's no number with a look-ahead:

```
.*getResource(?!\/\d+)
```

Comment: I see. Just to confirm,this pattern is for the 1st url right?

Comment: Basically I wanted to use 2 different patterns for the 2 strings urls. For the first,I use . *bins*.

Answer (score 0):

To match only the second url you can use this pattern:

```
.*getResource/([0-9]+)
```

Comment: Hmmm I think I kind of need a limiting pattern in the 2nd one to not match getResource.